# Eigenvalues Lie at the Boundary of Union of Gershgorin Circle

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Gersgorin disk theorem says that every eigenvalue of complex matrix $A$ which has size $n\times n$ lies at the union of Gershgorin disks. I want to know characteristic(s) of examples such that all eigenvalues lie at the boundary of the union of the disks. For example if $A=\begin{bmatrix}
0&2\\
-2&0
\end{bmatrix}$, then the eigenvalues are $2i$ and $-2i$ lie at the boundary. Are there any other example and can we know the characteristic of the examples?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slight generalization: Consider matrices $M$ where each row and each column have only a single non-zero entry: $m_i$ if it is off the main diagonal and $d_i$ if it is on the main diagonal. In this case the Gershgorin Circles are isolated points (the $d_i$) and circles centered at the origin (the $m_i$). The eigenvalues are obviously the entries themselves, since $M$ can be diagonalized with a permutation matrix. If we say that the $m_i$ all have the same modulus, and the $d_i$ all have modulus greater than the $m_i$ then you would have your desired result. Can you go further, probably but I don't know immediately how to do it.

Comment: Thank you. I think we also need $m_i$ to be not at the same coloumn,otherwise $0$ is eigenvalue which I guess is inside the disk.

Comment: That is true, which is why I said “each row and each column” have exactly one non zero entry.

Comment: Oops sorry I did not read carefully

Answer (score 0):

Your example can be generalized to matrices like
$$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & a \\ -a & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Yes, but are there more examples? What if we go to $n\times n$ with $n>2$?

Comment: Your question is very interesting! I’ve been trying with some matrices, I think the matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}0 & a & 0 \\ -a & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & a \end{pmatrix}$$ might also work

Comment: munoz yes. I want to know whether we can give more examples, like, can all entries of the matrix to be nonzero?